# How can I get Skype to show all chat messages on the left?

Tags: skype, chat, alignment

I have a problem with the horizontal alignment of chat bubbles in Skype. I am using Skype on various computers. So far all Skype installations have shown messages aligned to the left (chat partners messages on the very left, **my own messages also left but indented a bit**). Some what like this:

```
|Their message                        |
|  My message                         |
|Their message                        |
|  My message                         |
```

Now one Skype installation (on a Mac) shows **my messages aligned to the right**. Somewhat like this:

```
|Their message                        |
|                           My message|
|Their message                        |
|                           My message|
```

Could this be caused by some language settings? Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: This is one of those things I find so irritating. There some mystic key combo which makes it easy to change something with an accidental press of a button and which is so hard to reverse because you don't know what you did to make the switch happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still facing this issue in Skype. Right click mouse in the Chat message typing window and choose the option "Right-to-Left" reading order.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYzLC.png)

Comment: Doh! Right click menu! So obvious once you know :)

Answer (score 0):

I found an option in the Messaging preferences that does what you are looking for.

> Use full width message bubbles.